# Issues with solidity flash loan contract

Tags: solidity

So I'm playing with Aave's flash loan protocol and I can't get past this issue. The contract will only let me take a flash loan if my input amount is 100, doesn't matter what asset, and that's not to any decimal place. I enter anything higher then 100 and the contract reverts. Any help would be great.

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity 0.8.10;

import {FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase} from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/flashloan/base/FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase.sol";
import {IPoolAddressesProvider} from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/interfaces/IPoolAddressesProvider.sol";
import {IERC20} from "@aave/core-v3/contracts/dependencies/openzeppelin/contracts/IERC20.sol";


contract FlashLoan is FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase {
    address payable owner;
    address immutable debtUSDC = 0xFCCf3cAbbe80101232d343252614b6A3eE81C989;
    address immutable collUSDC = 0x625E7708f30cA75bfd92586e17077590C60eb4cD;
    


    constructor(address _addressProvider)
            FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase(IPoolAddressesProvider(_addressProvider)) {
            owner = payable(msg.sender);            
        }

        modifier onlyOwner() {
            require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can call this function");
            _;
        }

        // This is the body of the contract, the borrowed funds are here,
        // This is where the loan logic goes
        function executeOperation(
            address asset, // Asset to borrow
            uint256 amount, // Amount to borrow
            uint256 premium, // Fee for loan
            address  initiator, // Address of the flashloan initiator
            bytes calldata params //Byte incoded perameters passed when initiation the flashlaon
        ) external override returns (bool) {

            emit paramCheck (asset, amount, premium, address(POOL), params);

            uint256 amountOwed = amount + premium;
            uint256 interestRateMode = 2;
            uint16 referralCode = 0;

            approve(address(POOL), asset, (amountOwed + (amountOwed * 5 /100)));

            emit loanReceived (amountOwed);

            //POOL.repay(asset, IERC20(debtUSDC).balanceOf(address(owner)), interestRateMode, owner);
            //POOL.withdraw(asset, (IERC20(collUSDC).balanceOf(owner) * 90 / 100), initiator);

            // This determins if theres enough funds in contract holdings to pay back loan
            // If not, it checks the owners assets for remaining funds, if funds are unavailibe 
            // it borrows from aave supply to cover the differance
            if (getBalance(initiator, asset) <= amountOwed) {
                uint256 amountRequired = amountOwed - getBalance(initiator, asset);
                
                approve(owner, asset, (amountRequired + ((amountRequired + 1) * 15 / 100)));

                emit fundCheck (amountOwed, getBalance(initiator, asset), getBalance(owner, asset), 1);
                emit allowanceCheck (allowance(owner, initiator, asset));

                if (allowance(owner, initiator, asset) <= amountRequired && getBalance(initiator, asset) < amountOwed) {
                    POOL.borrow(asset, amountRequired, interestRateMode, referralCode, owner);
                    emit borrow (amountRequired, getBalance(initiator, asset));

                    return true;

                }  else if (allowance(owner, initiator, asset) > amountRequired) {
                    transfer(owner, initiator, asset, (amountRequired + ((amountRequired + 1) * 15 / 100)));
                    return true;
                }

            } else if (getBalance(initiator, asset) >= amountOwed) {
                return true;
            }

            emit allowanceCheck (allowance(address(POOL), initiator, asset));

            return true;
        }

        // This function initiates the flashloan with desired token and amount
        function requestFlashLoan(address _token, uint256 _amount) public {
            address receiverAddress = address(this); // Set to this contract
            address asset = _token;
            uint256 amount = _amount;
            bytes memory params = "";
            uint16 referralCode = 0;
            
            emit initCheck (receiverAddress, asset, amount, referralCode);

            POOL.flashLoanSimple(receiverAddress, asset, amount, params, referralCode);

        }

        function withdraw (address holder, address receiver, address asset, uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
            IERC20(asset).transferFrom(holder, receiver, amount);
        }

        function getBalance(address holder, address asset) internal view returns (uint256) {
            return IERC20(asset).balanceOf(holder);
        }

        function allowance(address sender, address spender, address asset) internal view returns (uint256) {
            return IERC20(asset).allowance(sender, spender);
        }

        function transfer(address sender, address receiver, address asset, uint256 amount) internal returns (bool) {
            IERC20(asset).transferFrom(sender, receiver, amount);
            emit tokensTransferd (true);
            return true;
        }

        function approve(address holder, address asset, uint256 amount) internal returns (bool) {
            IERC20(asset).approve(holder, amount);
            emit tokenApproved (true);
            return true;
        }

        event loanReceived (
            uint256 loanValue
        );

        event fundCheck (
            uint256 loanValue,
            uint256 contractHoldings,
            uint256 ownerHoldings,
            uint256 step
        );

        event allowanceCheck (
            uint256 allowance
        );

        event borrow (
            uint256 loanValue,
            uint256 contractHoldings
        );

        event tokenApproved (
            bool approved
        );

        event tokensTransferd (
            bool transferSuccesfull
        );

        event paramCheck (
            address asset,
            uint256 amount,
            uint256 premium,
            address POOL,
            bytes params
        );

        event initCheck (
            address receiverAddress, 
            address asset, 
            uint256 amount, 
            uint16 referralCode
        );
        
        // Enables contract to receive payments
        receive() external payable {}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to transfer asset tokens from my primary address to the contract address to cover the flash loan fee before the flash loan was requested. This would probably be rectified if the flash loan logic returned enough of a profit to cover the fee.